# Coq: unfold tricky notations

Tags: coq

Suppose I want to convert `~X` to `X -> False` using `unfold` tactic.

I have two options how to do it: either by `unfold not` or by `unfold "~"`.
The second way is apparently more convenient since there is no need to remember what definition name stays behind the notation.

However I haven't managed to do it in more complex cases:

```
Definition assn_sub X a P : Assertion :=
  fun (st : state) =>
    P (X !-> aeval st a ; st).

Notation "P [ X |-> a ]" := (assn_sub X a P)
  (at level 10, X at next level).
```

and I want to unfold it in expression

```
((fun st0 : state => st0 Y = st0 X + st0 Z) [Z |-> Y - X]) st
```

without using `assn_sub`. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With underscores, it seems to work.

```
unfold "_ [ _ |-> _ ]".
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without a reproducible example, but Ssreflect's unfold should work:

```
rewrite /(_[_|->_]).
```